# Modify Apache header using edit and perl regex

Tags: regex, apache, configuration, pcre

I could need some help using perl regular expressions.

I would like to modify the content-security-policy (csp) header of my apache webserver. The header is actually already set by my nextcloud instance, but I am not happy with what's in there. So I decided to modify (not replace) the header.
So far I tried using the following in my apache config:

```
Header edit Content-Security-Policy ^default-src\s'self'* "default-scr 'self' 'test'"
```

So far, so good. Unfortunately this only works if I want to replace the first entry of my csp, but what I want to do is change the second entry

```
default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-abc...'
```

should become

```
default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-abc...'
```

According to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) I am to use perl style regular expressions. I do not know how these work and trying vim-like syntax did not help. So please help me get the command right. Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
To give additional information, my header looks like

```
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-SU5kR1FZUGU5UW9jY2toRFh6VGR5a0hGMTFCY3ltL2d4RkN1QlFKaXJzST06U0w4MUJkZVJ4eUZaV1gwUGNGMkZoZ3UwbUdacG5oblFnbnZZWmxzUHpKTT0='; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; img-src * data: blob:; font-src 'self' data:; media-src *; connect-src *
```

where the nonce changes on every connection, so hard coding the header does not work.

Comment: Your question does not have Perl programming content. Re-tagged accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the pcre tag, that's why I had put perl at first.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your example change is correect, and not the sample edit line:

```
Header edit Content-Security-Policy "^(script-src.*? )'unsafe-eval'" "\1'unsafe-inline`"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Changing your line to
    `Header edit Content-Security-Policy "^(default-src.*? )'unsafe-eval'" "\1'unsafe-inline`"`
Does change the result to `1'unsafe-inline` 'nonce-abc...'`
I don'k know where the error is, but I adjusted my example, maybe I was not clear about what I wanted.

Comment: I think the backreference to the first group `\1` isn't making it through. You could try two backslashes.

Comment: Adding another backslash to `\1` did not help... But I have found the solution. Since I only have a single `unsafe-eval` (and thus want to replace all occurences) I used `Header edit Content-Security-Policy "(unsafe-eval)" "unsafe-inline"`. It gives the desired result, but renders the site unusable. Seems like nextcloud relies on `unsafe-eval`.

Comment: Apache uses $1 instead of \1. Took me some time to figure out.